# VS Code is not checking any of my files for Error

Tags: visual-studio-code, lint

Vs code is not checking any of my files for errors.

The below picture has an error at line: 13, cause I haven't imported the "Data" component.
But VScode is not showing any error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYaIy.png

VScode is just not checking any of my files, for example it lets me save a file like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNAMz.png

I have ESLint extension installed in VScode.

Please help me with this situation.

Comment: If you have [a jsconfig.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig), please also show that

Answer (score 0):

From [VScode Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116305)

Remove `"breadcrumbs.enabled": false` line from your VScode settings